# Can you perform SHOW TABLES query (or similar) with Microsoft Azure?

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to do this?

I need to get a list of all table names in the selected/connected database.

I have been experimenting with sql keyword EXPLAIN, DESCRIBE, SHOW TABLES etc but just get errors back from Azure:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'SHOW'.
```

Anyone know if its possible to do what Im trying to do?

Have tried:

```
$q = $this->db->query('
  SHOW TABLES
');

$query = $q->result_array();
```

Comment: can you post the code which you tried?

Comment: @Venkat He is showing what he tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a SELECT on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and if you want the columns as well, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this query.

```
select * from sys.tables;
```

[(based on a query here)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/04/09/sql-azure-list-of-tables-with-record-count.aspx)